# Как плавно зафиксировать элемент внизу страницы при прокрутке

Tags: javascript, css3

Есть текст на странице, под ним по центру идет кнопка на странице, и далее снова текст, и нужно чтобы  при прокрутке странице кнопка не исчезала из поля видимости, а была зафиксирована внизу слева, для этого нужно что бы при прокрутке, кнопка должна сначала переместилась влево, а затем зафиксировалась внизу страницы.
Пример разметки `html`:

```
<div>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores vitae omnis, fugiat nesciunt? Illum maxime eaque blanditiis reprehenderit incidunt nulla animi, cupiditate possimus, accusamus quidem in eum tenetur quod voluptas!</div> <button style="margin: 10 px auto"> кнопка</button> <div>Eligendi necessitatibus odio quasi officiis itaque fugit doloribus, numquam expedita totam facilis sit laborum dolores repellendus aliquam provident velit et accusamus reiciendis voluptates eaque inventore maiores unde sed. Nihil, excepturi.</div>
<div class="main">
    <div>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores vitae omnis, fugiat nesciunt? Illum maxime eaque blanditiis reprehenderit incidunt nulla animi, cupiditate possimus, accusamus quidem in eum tenetur quod voluptas!</div>
    <button class="button" id="button"> кнопка</button>
    <div>Eligendi necessitatibus odio quasi officiis itaque fugit doloribus, numquam expedita totam facilis sit laborum dolores repellendus aliquam provident velit et accusamus reiciendis voluptates eaque inventore maiores unde sed. Nihil, excepturi.</div>
    <div>Eligendi necessitatibus odio quasi officiis itaque fugit doloribus, numquam expedita totam facilis sit laborum dolores repellendus aliquam provident velit et accusamus reiciendis voluptates eaque inventore maiores unde sed. Nihil, excepturi.</div>
    <div>Eligendi necessitatibus odio quasi officiis itaque fugit doloribus, numquam expedita totam facilis sit laborum dolores repellendus aliquam provident velit et accusamus reiciendis voluptates eaque inventore maiores unde sed. Nihil, excepturi.</div>
    <div>Eligendi necessitatibus odio quasi officiis itaque fugit doloribus, numquam expedita totam facilis sit laborum dolores repellendus aliquam provident velit et accusamus reiciendis voluptates eaque inventore maiores unde sed. Nihil, excepturi.</div>
    <div>Eligendi necessitatibus odio quasi officiis itaque fugit doloribus, numquam expedita totam facilis sit laborum dolores repellendus aliquam provident velit et accusamus reiciendis voluptates eaque inventore maiores unde sed. Nihil, excepturi.</div>
    <div>Eligendi necessitatibus odio quasi officiis itaque fugit doloribus, numquam expedita totam facilis sit laborum dolores repellendus aliquam provident velit et accusamus reiciendis voluptates eaque inventore maiores unde sed. Nihil, excepturi.</div>
    <div>Eligendi necessitatibus odio quasi officiis itaque fugit doloribus, numquam expedita totam facilis sit laborum dolores repellendus aliquam provident velit et accusamus reiciendis voluptates eaque inventore maiores unde sed. Nihil, excepturi.</div>
    <div>Eligendi necessitatibus odio quasi officiis itaque fugit doloribus, numquam expedita totam facilis sit laborum dolores repellendus aliquam provident velit et accusamus reiciendis voluptates eaque inventore maiores unde sed. Nihil, excepturi.</div>
    <div>Eligendi necessitatibus odio quasi officiis itaque fugit doloribus, numquam expedita totam facilis sit laborum dolores repellendus aliquam provident velit et accusamus reiciendis voluptates eaque inventore maiores unde sed. Nihil, excepturi.</div>
    <div>Eligendi necessitatibus odio quasi officiis itaque fugit doloribus, numquam expedita totam facilis sit laborum dolores repellendus aliquam provident velit et accusamus reiciendis voluptates eaque inventore maiores unde sed. Nihil, excepturi.</div>
    <div>Eligendi necessitatibus odio quasi officiis itaque fugit doloribus, numquam expedita totam facilis sit laborum dolores repellendus aliquam provident velit et accusamus reiciendis voluptates eaque inventore maiores unde sed. Nihil, excepturi.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Анастасия Чтобы была возможность ответить на Ваш вопрос, добавьте, пожалуйста, Вашу разметку `html` и приложите `css`. В этом случае Вам обязательно помогут. Пока не понятно как она должна именно смещаться, и что в какой момент фиксироваться внизу страницы.

Comment: <div>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores vitae omnis, fugiat nesciunt? Illum maxime eaque blanditiis reprehenderit incidunt nulla animi, cupiditate possimus, accusamus quidem in eum tenetur quod voluptas!</div>
<button style="margin: 10 px auto"> кнопка</button>
<div>Eligendi necessitatibus odio quasi officiis itaque fugit doloribus, numquam expedita totam facilis sit laborum dolores repellendus aliquam provident velit et accusamus reiciendis voluptates eaque inventore maiores unde sed. Nihil, excepturi.</div>

Comment: Это не серьёзно. Вы просто написали стандартный `div` коих в интернете множество. В Вашем случае всё равно остается непонятно, что у Вас за разметка, где находится кнопка, куда должна смещаться и относительно чего. Если Вы можете предоставить лишь такие данные, как указали, то, к сожалению, Вам никто не сможет помочь.

Comment: div{
padding: 10px 20px
}
кнопка должна сместиться в левый отступ div 20px

Comment: понимаю что при скролле нужно задать кнопки стили position: absolut; left: 0; что бы она переместилась влево, проблема в том что не знаю как отследить что кнопка покидает зону видимости экрана, что бы задать ей position: fixed; bottom: 0

Comment: @Анастасия вы можете нажать изменить вопрос и найти в панели для написания вопроса картинку, документ со знаками <>, на нём будет написано фрагмент кода на JavaScript/HTML/CSS, в этом редакторе вам надо вставить ваш HTML и CSS код, чтобы все могли прямо тут посмотреть и помочь не гадая на кофейной гуще

Answer (score 1):

```js
    window.onload = function () { // При загрузке страницы
        let posbutton = document.getElementsByClassName('button')[0]; // Получаем кнопку по классу
        let yc = posbutton.getBoundingClientRect().y; // Получаем его координаты Y
        window.addEventListener('scroll', function () { // Отслеживаем скролл
            let yy = window.pageYOffset; // Получаем координаты страницы при прокрутке
            if (yy >= yc){ // Если координаты Y страницы больше y элемента, то...
                posbutton.style.position = "fixed"; // Фиксируем положение кнопки
                posbutton.style.bottom = '0px'; // Прижимаем книзу
            } else {
                posbutton.style.position = "relative"; // Если больше, то возвращаем обратно.
            }
        })
    }
```

```css
    .main{
        width: 200px;
    }
    .button{
        margin: auto;
        left: 35%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores vitae omnis, fugiat nesciunt? Illum maxime eaque blanditiis reprehenderit incidunt nulla animi, cupiditate possimus, accusamus quidem in eum tenetur quod voluptas!</div>
    <button class="button" id="button"> кнопка</button>
    <div>Eligendi necessitatibus odio quasi officiis itaque fugit doloribus, numquam expedita totam facilis sit laborum dolores repellendus aliquam provident velit et accusamus reiciendis voluptates eaque inventore maiores unde sed. Nihil, excepturi.</div>
    <div>Eligendi necessitatibus odio quasi officiis itaque fugit doloribus, numquam expedita totam facilis sit laborum dolores repellendus aliquam provident velit et accusamus reiciendis voluptates eaque inventore maiores unde sed. Nihil, excepturi.</div>
    <div>Eligendi necessitatibus odio quasi officiis itaque fugit doloribus, numquam expedita totam facilis sit laborum dolores repellendus aliquam provident velit et accusamus reiciendis voluptates eaque inventore maiores unde sed. Nihil, excepturi.</div>
    <div>Eligendi necessitatibus odio quasi officiis itaque fugit doloribus, numquam expedita totam facilis sit laborum dolores repellendus aliquam provident velit et accusamus reiciendis voluptates eaque inventore maiores unde sed. Nihil, excepturi.</div>
    <div>Eligendi necessitatibus odio quasi officiis itaque fugit doloribus, numquam expedita totam facilis sit laborum dolores repellendus aliquam provident velit et accusamus reiciendis voluptates eaque inventore maiores unde sed. Nihil, excepturi.</div>
    <div>Eligendi necessitatibus odio quasi officiis itaque fugit doloribus, numquam expedita totam facilis sit laborum dolores repellendus aliquam provident velit et accusamus reiciendis voluptates eaque inventore maiores unde sed. Nihil, excepturi.</div>
    <div>Eligendi necessitatibus odio quasi officiis itaque fugit doloribus, numquam expedita totam facilis sit laborum dolores repellendus aliquam provident velit et accusamus reiciendis voluptates eaque inventore maiores unde sed. Nihil, excepturi.</div>
    <div>Eligendi necessitatibus odio quasi officiis itaque fugit doloribus, numquam expedita totam facilis sit laborum dolores repellendus aliquam provident velit et accusamus reiciendis voluptates eaque inventore maiores unde sed. Nihil, excepturi.</div>
    <div>Eligendi necessitatibus odio quasi officiis itaque fugit doloribus, numquam expedita totam facilis sit laborum dolores repellendus aliquam provident velit et accusamus reiciendis voluptates eaque inventore maiores unde sed. Nihil, excepturi.</div>
    <div>Eligendi necessitatibus odio quasi officiis itaque fugit doloribus, numquam expedita totam facilis sit laborum dolores repellendus aliquam provident velit et accusamus reiciendis voluptates eaque inventore maiores unde sed. Nihil, excepturi.</div>
    <div>Eligendi necessitatibus odio quasi officiis itaque fugit doloribus, numquam expedita totam facilis sit laborum dolores repellendus aliquam provident velit et accusamus reiciendis voluptates eaque inventore maiores unde sed. Nihil, excepturi.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: почти так, но мне нужно что бы сначала кнопка плавно переместилась вправо, или влево не важно, и только потом зафиксировалась внизу, а сейчас она прыгает